# Enterprise Wifi disconnected

Tags: networking, network-manager, wireless-access-point

When I am connecting to my company wifi which is an enterprise WPA2 network, using PEAP authentication and MSCHAPv2 I got connected well for like 1 or 2 minutes then I got disconnected for like 1 or 2 minutes and then I got connected again. this happens over and over.

when I see the logs of the network manager I got these logs.

so can you help me, please

```
- Logs begin at Mon 2020-10-19 12:12:22 EET. --
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.7811] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8083] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8084] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "my_wifi"
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8085] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8089] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8172] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8261] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8264] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:07:52 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246872.8313] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
 01 18:08:19 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246899.2526] agent-manager: agent[8028664e8adffc30,:1.86/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
 01 18:09:35 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <warn>  [1604246975.0916] sup-iface[0x556ebb472910,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 3)
 01 18:09:35 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246975.0964] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
 01 18:09:35 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246975.0964] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
 01 18:09:35 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246975.1962] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 01 18:09:35 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246975.1963] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 01 18:09:38 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246978.5101] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
 01 18:09:38 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246978.5102] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
 01 18:09:38 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246978.7141] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
 01 18:09:38 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246978.7142] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
 01 18:09:39 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246979.2142] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 01 18:09:39 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246979.2143] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 01 18:09:50 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <warn>  [1604246990.0791] device (wlp2s0): link timed out.
 01 18:09:50 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246990.0792] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:09:50 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <warn>  [1604246990.0828] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'my_wifi'
 01 18:09:50 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246990.0853] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:09:50 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246990.1350] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
 01 18:09:50 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246990.1351] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
 01 18:09:57 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246997.1311] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
 01 18:09:57 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604246997.1315] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4431] policy: auto-activating connection 'my_wifi' (b9793100-ef09-47f4-aba9-3e74d0914cc3)
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4439] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'my_wifi' (b9793100-ef09-47f4-aba9-3e74d0914cc3)
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4441] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4450] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4454] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'my_wifi' has security, but secrets are required.
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4455] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4504] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4509] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4514] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'my_wifi' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4515] Config: added 'ssid' value 'my_wifi'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4515] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4515] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4515] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256 FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4515] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4516] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4516] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4516] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4516] Config: added 'identity' value 'whatever'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4516] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4793] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4794] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4853] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.4853] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.5173] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.5173] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9316] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9317] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9653] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9654] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "my_wifi"
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9655] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9662] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9723] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:00 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247000.9996] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:01 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247001.0000] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 01 18:10:01 My_Labtop NetworkManager[691]: <info>  [1604247001.0062] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

Comment: As it obvious that the log on your side does not provide any useful information, next thing I would do is to ask the sysop responsible for the server if there is better information in the server log.